# Lorentz invariant measures in phase space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, integration, phase-space

I am trying to figure out how exactly you show an integration measure is Lorentz invariant, and in particular derive the Lorentz invariant phase space measure used in QFT. To do that, some sources restrict the measure $d^4$ to the mass shell. If that measure is Lorentz invariant, then obviously its restriction to the Lorentz invariant mass shell is also Lorentz invariant I guess. So that's cool. But here is the issue: it's not obvious to me how to rigorously prove it is Lorentz invariant in the first place.

I've seen the following expression in a couple of places:

$$ dp_\mu dp^\mu = d^4 p $$

I don't understand this. It doesn't even seem like it makes dimensional sense in my eyes. Of course I can see that the left hand side is Lorentz invariant, but how does it correspond to the right hand side?

Comment: Which places? Which pages?

Comment: "I've seen the following expression in a couple of places..." Have you? Where? It is nonsense.

Comment: The equation $d^4p=dp_\mu dp^\mu$ is simply not correct. The object $ϵ=d^4p\sqrt{-g}$, where $g$ is the metric in momentum space written in whatever coordinates you want, is a volume-form in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$. As such, it is a four-form. The quantity $dp_\mu dp^\mu$ is not a four-form. If we interpret the product as a generic tensor product or the symmetric tensor product the resulting object is simply not even a differential-form. If we interpret it as a wedge product the result is simply zero because $\omega\wedge\omega=0$ for any one-form $\omega$

Comment: And even if it were not zero, the result could be at most a two-form, so certainly not equal to $\epsilon=d^4p\sqrt{-g}$ which is a four-form.

Comment: I've seen it in two places, the first I don't remember, the other was another stackexchange answer so not anything reputable... Sorry, I just got a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measure $d^4p$ is trivially invariant under Lorentz transformations. The reason is that under the transformation $p^\mu\to p'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu}p^\nu$ the measure transforms by a Jacobian

$$d^4p\to d^4p' = \left|\dfrac{\partial p'^\mu}{\partial p^\nu}\right|d^4p=|\det \Lambda|d^4p.$$

But a Lorentz transformation obeys

$$\eta = \Lambda^T \eta \Lambda\Longrightarrow \det\Lambda=\pm 1,$$

where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. As a result $d^4p' = d^4p$ and the measure is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Oh right, the Jacobian... Damn I can't believe I didn't remember that...

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen that last expression nor did I use it when showing that $d^4p$ is Lorentz invariant, which I did in my QFT course. Maybe someone else knows better about it, if you have seen it in reliable sources.

If you already have the measure written as $d^4p$ then the proof just comes down to $det(\Lambda)=1$, since that is what you get when changing integration measure. We are assuming here a proper Lorentz transformation, so without time reversal or spatial reflection, or else we could get $det(\Lambda)=-1$.

The next step is usually to show, starting from this, that $\frac{d^3p}{2E_p}$ is lorentz invariant. The proof of this is pretty easy to find online, there is a trick with writing it in terms of a delta function with a $d^4p$ integration measure.

Comment: I have one more question that might be stupid, that Lorentz invariant measure ahs dimension momentum squared, aka area in phase space. It perplexes me a little bit because my intuition is that it measures the hyperboloid p^2=m^2, which should be a volume, right?

Comment: The Lorentz invariant measure has dimension momentum$^4$, so I don't know what you mean by that. Those two expressions you wrote are simply not equal I believe.

Comment: I mean the final measure on the hyperboloid that you mentioned.